# Getting the integers from a string

Tags: javascript, regex

How can I get the set integers after the 2nd `:` from a string using regex?

Please see the examples:

```
input: '<a:test:398324781412777419>' ==> output: '398324781412777419'
input: '<a:10test:391278741412111419>' ==> output: '391278741412111419'
input: '<a:test10:123487466611419>' ==> output: '123487466611419'
```

Comment: seems like a simple reg expression. What did you try? Or a simple split would work.

Comment: @epascarello I tried this `string.match(/<:[\w]+:[\d]+>/g)[0].replace (/[^\d.]/g, '')` but got the error:  `Cannot read property '0' of null`

Comment: What about `^[^:]+:[^:]+:(\d+)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a regular expression which looks for digits and a following `>`.

The regular expression has two parts,

```
/\d+(?=>$)/
 ^^^         search for digits
    (?=  )   pattern for positive lookahead (the part is not included in the result)
       >$    looks for character > and for end of string
```

```js
var string = '<a:test:398324781412777419>',
    number = string.match(/\d+(?=>$)/)[0];
    
console.log(number);
```

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks. Could you please explain what `(?=>$)` does?

Answer (score 1):

```js
var str = `
input: '<a:test:398324781412777419>' ==> output: '398324781412777419'
input: '<a:10test:391278741412111419>' ==> output: '391278741412111419'
input: '<a:test10:123487466611419>' ==> output: '123487466611419'`;

var matches = str.match(/:(\d+)>/g)
  .map(itm=>parseInt(itm.substr(1, itm.length-2)));

console.log(matches);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.replace(/[^:]?[^:]?(\D)/g, '')`.

Example:

`'<a:test10:398324781412777419>'.replace(/[^:]?[^:]?(\D)/g, '')
// will return '398324781412777419'`

Comment: However, `'<a:10test:391278741412111419>'` would output  `10391278741412111419`, I would like to disregard the integers before the 2nd `:`